# How to add multiple nodes of different objects?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to make an app similar to waazy. The problem I am facing and i searched the internet unfortunately couldn't find any answer to this is I want to add multiple 3d objects. Let say I have a 3d horse, a dinosaur and a human model.

I want to know how exactly can I create them and set them in the collection view so when user select horse from collectionView and tap on the screen horse should appear and if he select the dinosaur from the collectionView and tap's on the screen dinosaur will appear but till now I cannot find any solution for this online please help me solve this problem.

I am assuming I will have to create an Array of nodes if possible but I really don't know how to make an Array of nodes since you have to create texture, etc.